# What type of diet is effective at eliminating small intestinal bacterial overgrowth?

Tags: diet, bacteria, fodmap, sibo

What type of diet is effective at eliminating small intestinal bacterial overgrowth (SIBO) and how long does one need to be on it?

Comment: What is SIBO? That might make this answerable

Comment: **Small Intestinal Bacteria Overgrowth (SIBO)** Maybe include that in your question

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Spelling out the acronym along with some of your own research would help the answerers write better answers for you. We can't really share experiences, since that doesn't fit the SE model, but have to write facts backed up with science. You can always [edit] your question to add more details. For more information please see [ask], the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!